# SQl Transactions - query doesnt return value as expected

Tags: c#, sql, stored-procedures

**tblParent**

```
pid(int) name deleted(bit)
1        abc   0
2        def   0
```

**tblChild**

```
cid(int) name  pid(ForeignKey)
1        aaa   1
2        bbb   1
```

When a record from `tblParent` is being deleted, it should check for any child records. If yes, rollback & return 0. If no, then update the deleted column to '1' and return 1.
Basically, doing a soft delete

The SP works fine. All I need is to know the status as 0 or 1 based upon the action that took place. How should it be done. I would call this store procedure from c#, linq to entities to get the status.
 something like:

```
public int somefuntion() //returning a string is also fine..
   {
     return MYDB.SoftDelete(parameters.....);
   }
```

**EDIT:**

```
ALTER PROCEDURE SoftDelete
(
  @TableName nvarchar(50), @ColName nvarchar(50),
  @Id nvarchar(50)
)
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @qry nvarchar(500)

  SELECT @qry = 'begin transaction
                 delete '+@tablename+' where '+@colname+'='+@id+'
                 if(@@Error <> 0)
                  Begin
                    --select 0
                  End
                 else
                  Begin
                   rollback transaction
               update '+@tablename+' set deleted = 1 where '+@colname+' = '+@id+'
                   --select = 1
                  end'

   EXECUTE sp_executesql @qry
END
```

Comment: is @status part of the calling code or part of the executed dynamic sql? You use it both ways, it can't work like this

Comment: Its just a variable to store 1 or 0, so that I can use it later in c#

Comment: see my second answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Declare @status nvarchar(50),@tablename nvarchar(50), @colname nvarchar(50),
@id nvarchar(50), @qry nvarchar(500)
set @tablename  = 'person'
set @colname = 'id'
set @id = '15'
begin try
begin transaction
 set @qry='delete '+@tablename+' where '+@colname+'=@id'
 execute sp_executesql @qry,N'@id nvarchar(50)',@id=@id
 rollback 
 --NO FK violation.So begin another transaction and soft delete
 begin transaction
set @qry='update '+@tablename +' set deleted=1 where '+@colname+'=@id'

execute sp_executesql @qry,N'@id nvarchar(50)',@id=@id
commit

select 1

end try

begin catch
print(Error_Message())
--FK violation.Do nothing.Return 0
select 0

end catch
```

Comment: Check if the tableName and columnName you are passing are correct.

Comment: I am afraid that your approach is gonna work...even though you are checking @@Error<>0, it will throw an exception whenever a referential integrity constraint is violated which inturn will put your c# code into exception.So you need to add try catch in the stored procedure.

Comment: If I understood correctly,if there is any FK violation, you need a soft delete [deleted=1] and you want to return 1.But if there is not FK violation, you need a hard delete [delete table where....] and in that case you want to return 0. If this is your requirement,then see my updated answer above.

Comment: I think the following link answers your question.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1168890/checking-rule-violations-before-deleting-a-record

Comment: I think this meets your requirement.See my updated answer and try it.

Comment: I figured it out. There has to be a rollback in catch too. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

**In your script the  @status variable is not accessible inside your sql statement you build because "execute sp_executesql @qry" will be executing in different space.  Instead use select n" in replace to "set @status = 0" and "set @status = 1"**

Try this

```
Declare @tablename nvarchar(50), @colname nvarchar(50),
        @id nvarchar(50), @qry nvarchar(500)
set @tablename  = 'tblParent'
set @colname = 'pid'
set @id = '1'

select @qry = 'begin transaction
               delete '+@tablename+' where '+@colname+'='+@id+'
               if(@@Error <> 0)
                Begin
                  select 0
                End
               else
                Begin
                 rollback transaction
               update '+@tablename+' set deleted = 1 where '+@colname+' = '+@id+'
                 select 1
                end

execute sp_executesql @qry
```

Comment: :)Just tried that. "Transaction count after EXECUTE indicates a mismatching number of BEGIN and COMMIT statements. Previous count = 0, current count = 1."...The query is working fine. When there is a constraint it gives the error, and when not, it updates the column. All that is need to find from C# if it was a 0 or 1. What about using 'return'

Comment: i c# use command query and it return table, Execute() will return value set in Return